# Django update model in shell not saving

Tags: django, django-shell

I´m trying to update the data of an existing model with a csv. I read the file and assign the values with no problem.

If I try `MyModel.update() everything runs with no error but the data is not saved.

```
with open('Productosold.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
        p = ProductosBase.objects.filter(codigo_barra = row['codigo_barra'])
        p.region=row['region']
        p.producto_ing=row['producto_ing']
        p.packaging_ing=row['packaging_ing']
        p.precio_compra=row['precio_compra']
        p.uom=row['uom']
        p.units_inner=row['units_inner']
        p.inner_master=row['inner_master']
        p.tier=row['tier']
        p.precio_lista_internacional=row['precio_lista_internacional']
        p.update()
```

I usualy upload new data using the `MyModel.save()` method and have no problem. 
Now, if I use that I get "Queryset has no attribute save".

```
p.save()
```

If I print some of the p.values I can see they are populated correctly from the csv file.

What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` always returns a queryset, not a single instance. When you set all those values, you are just setting (previously non-existing) attributes onto that queryset object; you are not setting fields in a model instance. You should use `.get` to get an instance and save that.

```
p = ProductosBase.objects.get(codigo_barra = row['codigo_barra'])
p.region=row['region']
...
p.save()
```

However, since all the columns in your CSV map precisely to fields on the model, you could in fact use `filter` and `update` to do the whole thing in one go:

```
for row in reader:
    ProductosBase.objects.filter(codigo_barra=row['codigo_barra']).update(**row)
```

and no need for any of the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! That is a very classy solution. Love it.

Answer (score -1):

You need `filter()` whenever you expect more than just one object that matches your criteria. If no item was found matching your criteria, `filter()` returns am empty queryset without throwing an error.

Also you can use `get()` but when you expect one (and only one) item that matches your criteria. Get throws an error if the item does not exist or if multiple items exist that match your criteria. You should therefore always use if in a `try.. except ..` block or with a shortcut function like `get_object_or_404` in order to handle the exceptions properly. I'd recommend using `get_object_or_404` in this case.

```
p = get_object_or_404(ProductosBase, codigo_barra=row['codigo_barra'])
```

Comment: The question clearly states the code is being run from the shell. It makes no sense to raise a 404 in the shell.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for noting that ! But that doesn't make sense. It's for in order to handle exceptions properly.

Comment: What? `get_object_or_404` *raises* an exception. But it's an exception that only applies in a web request, causing the server to return a 404 error code. It's of no use in a try/except block; `.get()` will already raise the more appropriate exception, which is ModelDoesNotExist.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for information. Yes you're right. If this will be run in web request, it's better to use `get_object_or_404`. But if it's in shell, your variant would be better.